# Excel: Output more (calculated) lines based on a single criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to split a single line of information when it meets certain criteria, into several.

In the attached example, I'd like to split the lines with a number of 2 or more in the "Records" column, keeping the number 1 on each new line; but the "Amount" should be distributed within the new lines as well.

I attached a file with the information and the expected outcome in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nsbah933u0p1yvi/CHALLENGEa.xlsx?dl=0 and it is pasted below:

[image: Example]

Comment: How's your VBA?  I think you're going to need a macro solution

Comment: You can do it without VBA, though it's a touch complex and obviously much-better suited to a VBA approach.

Comment: I haven't tried VBA.
Since there's a limited amount of records per query, I thought of creating a blank spreadsheet to read every record from the original one and expand the required records. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses just basic Excel functions.  Say the source table pictured in your link starts in column A and the first row of data is row 2.  First, add a helper column starting in H2.  This column calculates the relative row each new name will start in for the new table.

Enter `1` in cell H2.  The formula in H3 would be:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",SUM(C$2:C2)+1)
```

Copy that down the column for all of the source data rows and as many others as you want to pre-populate.  It will remain blank where not needed.

Your output table starts in column I with row 2 being the first data.  Since your example has five rows of data, I'll base the solution formulas on that.  Just change the reference ranges as appropriate.  The formula in I2 (your Number column) would be:

```
    =IF((ROW()-1)>SUM(C$2:C$6),"",MATCH(ROW()-1,H$2:H$6,1))
```

You can copy this down the column an arbitrarily large range to pre-populate the cells you might eventually use.  This and all of the other entries in the table will remain blank until needed.

The Date column is J.  The formula in J2 is:

```
    =IF(I2="","",VLOOKUP(I2,$A$2:$F$6,2,))
```

The Name and ID columns are similar, just VLOOKUPs in a different column, so the formulas in M2 and N2 are:

```
    =IF(I2="","",VLOOKUP(I2,$A$2:$F$6,5,))   (cell M2)
    =IF(I2="","",VLOOKUP(I2,$A$2:$F$6,6,))   (cell N2)
```

You can just copy the J2 formula and edit the VLOOKUP column (last parameter).

In the output table, the Records column will always be `1`, so cell K2 is:

```
    =IF(I2="","",1)
```

The remaining column is Amount, which uses two VLOOKUPs for the numerator and denominator of your division.  Cell L2 would be:

```
    =IF(I2="","",VLOOKUP(I2,$A$2:$F$6,4,)/VLOOKUP(I2,$A$2:$F$6,3,))
```

If the date column appears as a number, just change the cell format to the desired date format.  Now you can copy the all of those cells down as you did for column I.

That will give you the output shown in your example.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I set up several columns with these formulas at the left of the blank space where the data will be pasted and got the results I needed then read by a pivot table.
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has a List.Generate function that can achieve what you want.

I've built a solution using your data which you can view or download - its: "Power Query demo - generate multiple rows from cell values.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Most of this was built using the point-and-click Power Query UI.  The List.Generate function is documented here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/list-generate-HA104111647.aspx

There aren't many practical examples out on the web, and I couldn't quite figure out how to pass it the Records value, so I'm just generating 10 rows then filtering in a later step.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thank you very much for sharing. I feel lucky to have received two solutions and will, in this occasion, go for fixer1234's one.
The main reason for this is that we need minimal human input after capturing data.

Comment: Perhaps you've missed something fundamental about Power Query.  You build and save your Query definitions.  Then in the future to re-run them, you just open the file and hit Data / Refresh All (even that step can be automated by setting the Connections to Refresh on open). PQ is more automated than copying formulas.

Comment: I've just updated my demo after getting some help from the PQ Team on the List.Generate function.  It will now generate any number of Records.